# Is it possible to make the given inputs into seperate variables?

Tags: python, variables

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p = map(int, nums.split(' '))
```

print (a)
print (b)

Is it possible to make the inputs given in `nums` into their own separate variables.

Comment: Yes, why do you think it might not be possible?

Comment: @mkrieger1 how would i do it? am i going about it right? I looked around and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @DACHICKENWINGS Have you tried running your own code?

Comment: @PaulM. yes, it says list has no attribute split

Comment: Did you mean `map(int, nums)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the only thing i had found was how i had done it but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

The map function returns a generator object,  You can cast it to a list by calling `list()`.

For example:

```py
lst = list(map(int, nums))
```

Then you can access each item by indexing

```py
a = lst[0]
b = lst[1]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Another method to achieve the same thing would be list-comprehension...

like this:

```
lst = [int(i) for i in nums]
a = lst[0]
b = lst[1]
print(a,b)
```

```py
>>> nums = '123456789' 
>>> map(int, nums)  # map object is a generator
<map object at 0x000001699F90F5E0>
>>> list(map(int,nums))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [int(i) for i in nums]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```